# function has no inflection point but second derivative =0

Tags: derivatives

I got this question for a finals review:[image]

The answer says it has no inflection point, but I got the second derivative to be

y''=2-2sinx

And when y''=0, x=2kπ+π/2

So how can this be?

Thanks.

P.S. The homework tag seems to be gone for some reason, so I can't add the tag.

Comment: As another example, consider a line $y=ax+b$. Then in fact the second derivative is zero for *all* values of $x$, but of course there are no inflection points.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to make use of **test points**. What happens immediately to the left/right of a zero of the second derivative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inflection point means the second derivative changes sign. This may or may not happen when the derivative is $0$. It doesn't happen here, the second derivative is always nonnegative.

Comment: oohh I see. thank you.

Comment: But I thought that happiness was the same as being positive!

Comment: @user Sigh... :) Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: The second derivative is not always positive.

Comment: @zhw. I mean non negative sorry